# Oracle, DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT

Tags: database, oracle

When I want to do 'dbms_session.set_context' then oracle returns error like these:

```
insufficient privileges  SYS.DBMS_SESSION, line 14
SCHEMA1.PACK_NAME ERROR at line 1: ORA-01031:
insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SESSION", line 94
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: well you have to grant privelges

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/context.html

Comment: Ask your DBA to grant the 'execute' privilege on SYS.DBMS_SESSION to schema1

Answer (score 0):

What is the SQL? In order to use DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT, you have to create a context, then specify where it can be set from, like

```
create context APPLICATION_SCOPE using MYSCHEMA.SET_APPLICATION_SCOPE
```

Then, in the procedure SET_APPLICATION_SCOPE, you could do the following:

```
DBMS_SESSION_SET_CONTEXT('APPLICATION_SCOPE','SOME_VARIABLE', 'SOME_VALUE');
```